# How to get the length of an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I need to get length of an array inside an array for my iteration.

I have three arrays that contain names from three different majors in my college 
that nested in one array called 'jurusan' that means major in English.

and I want to put all that names into three new groups that contain names from three different majors and put it inside each group.

How can I access the length of the Array contained inside jurusan?
my code reads the length of jurusan which is 3, it should get the length of tif array which is 5 and so on.

```js
var tif = ['idris', 'akbar', 'adyusman', 'a', 'g'];
var te = ['tolaal', 'badri', 'alaina', 'b'];
var mt = ['ressi', 'arian', 'tifa', 'c'];
var jurusan = [tif, te, mt];

var kel = [
  [],
  [],
  []
];

for (i = 0; i < jurusan.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < jurusan[i][j].length; j++) {
    kel[j].push(jurusan[i][j]);
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < kel.length; i++) {
  console.log(kel[i])
}
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = kel[0] + '<br>' + kel[1] + '<br>' + kel[2];
```

```html
<p id="a"></p>
```

Comment: Do you want to print whole array lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I access the length of the Array contained inside jurusan?

It seems pretty straight to me:

```js
var tif = ['idris','akbar','adyusman','a','g'];
var te = ['tolaal','badri','alaina','b'];
var mt = ['ressi','arian','tifa','c'];
var jurusan= [tif,te,mt];
// with forEach()
jurusan.forEach(n => console.log(n.length));
// with index
console.log(jurusan[0].length);
console.log(jurusan[1].length);
console.log(jurusan[2].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

const input = [ ['a', 'b', 'c', 's', '1s'], ['c', 'd', 'f'], ['d', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ]; const arrayOfLength = (prop) => { let length = prop.map(num => num.length) console.log(length) }
arrayOfLength(input)

// expected output  [5, 3, 4]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).